# Flutter Dart - 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<int, Color>'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WpCreateColor {
  final Color wpColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 77, 203, 79);

  MaterialColor createMaterialColor() {
    List strengths = <double>[.05];
    Map swatch = <int, Color>{};
    final int r = wpColor.red, g = wpColor.green, b = wpColor.blue;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      strengths.add(0.1 * i);
    }
    strengths.forEach((strength) {
      final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
      swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
        r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
        g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
        b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
        1,
      );
    });
    return MaterialColor(wpColor.value, swatch);
  }
}
```

And it gives the following error:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> swatch
The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<int, Color>'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: try using `Map<int, Color> swatch = {};`

Comment: @Sahdeep Singh Brilliant! It worked. Do you think you can put this info as the answer as well so that I can accept it as the official answer?

Comment: You can add it and accept OR answer below is good as well, you can accept that as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 8 of the code above the variable `swatch` is defined as a `Map` which by default is type `dynamic`, so the full type of `swatch` is created as `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`, however the value for this variable is assigned to a value of `Map<int,Color>` this is why you get an error.

To fix this **change**:

`Map swatch = <int, Color>{};`

to

`final swatch = <int, Color>{};`

A suggestion in dart is to omit types for local variables, because

> Usually, the types of local variables can be easily inferred, so it
> isn’t necessary to annotate them.

Visit the [dart docs](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#omit_local_variable_types) for more info on this suggestion